# POST call doesn't work correctly?

Tags: php, html, json, rest, post

I need to do a POST call to save data on a server. The server requires for some items a `JSON-Encoded List`. However when I do the post call and I look at `$result`, the data of the "JSON-Encoded List" is not saved and the items are `null`. The POST call is however successful.

```
$items = json_encode((array(
    "name" => $_GET['title'],
    "sub_type" => $subtype_fd,
    "calories" => intval($_GET['calories']),
    "carbohydrate" => floatval($_GET['carbohydrate']),
    "cholesterol" => floatval($_GET['cholesterol']),
    "fiber" => floatval($_GET['fiber']),
    "protein" => floatval($_GET['protein']),
    "saturated_fat" => floatval($_GET['saturated_fat']),
    "unsaturated_fat" => floatval($_GET['unsaturated_fat']),
    "sodium" => floatval($_GET['sodium']),
    "sugar" => floatval($_GET['sugar'])
)));

var_dump($items);

$data = array('note' => $_GET['title'], 'sub_type' => $subtype_bld, 'items' => $items);

$options = array(
    'http' => array(
        "header" => "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\nAuthorization: Bearer {$_COOKIE['access_token']}\r\n",
        'method' => 'POST',
        'content' => $data
    ),
);

$context  = stream_context_create($options);
$result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
```

The Info from API

```
Host: jawbone.com 
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: multipart/form-data
```

Answer (score 2):

The `content` context option should be a string, you're providing an array. It's supposed to be a string in URL-encoded format. The `http_build_str` function will convert an associative array into this format. So use:

```
'content' => http_build_str($data)
```

Comment: Now I got an error: ( ! ) Fatal error: Call to undefined function http_build_str()

Comment: See the user note at the end of http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-str.php

Comment: Does that mean I have to add new \http\QueryString(); to the top of the php?